# Stripping leading characters from command parameter

Tags: indexing, parsing

I have a command (AlertShort) with one input parameter that both prints text and generates an index.  For standard text this works fine but, in some cases, the input parameter contains a symbol which causes the index to sort incorrectly.  That can be fixed by prefixing the parameter with "@" to control the sort order but then the sort code gets printed with the text.

So I'd like to pass the parameter including its sort code directly to the index but to strip the sort code before printing the text.  In the MWE, I'm using a capital letter to give the required sort order and prefixing that with a quote mark so that the symbols appear first in the index.

MWE

```
    \documentclass{article}%

    \usepackage{fontspec}%
    \newfontfamily\symbolfamily{Asana Math}  

    \usepackage[hyperref, x11names]{xcolor}

    \usepackage{imakeidx}\makeindex%

    \usepackage[bookmarks, psdextra, unicode, hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%

    \DeclareRobustCommand\Bts{{\symbolfamily\char"2663}}
    \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
      \renewcommand\Bts{\Uchar"2663\relax}%
      % Inside PDF strings, \Ts is replaced by Unicode char U+2663 "BLACK CLUB SUIT"
    }

    \DeclareRobustCommand\Bks{{\color{red}\symbolfamily\char"2666}}
    \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
      \renewcommand\Bks{\Uchar"2666\relax}%
    }

    \DeclareRobustCommand\Bcs{{\color{red}\symbolfamily\char"2665}}
    \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
      \renewcommand\Bcs{\Uchar"2665\relax}%
    }

    \DeclareRobustCommand\Bps{{\symbolfamily\char"2660}}
    \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
      \renewcommand\Bps{\Uchar"2660\relax}%
    }

    \newcommand{\Ts}{"C@\Bts}% 
    \newcommand{\Ks}{"D\Bks}% 
    \newcommand{\Cs}{"H@\Bcs}% 
    \newcommand{\Ps}{"S@\Bps}% 

    \newcommand{\AlertShort}[1]{Alert: #1\index[alerts]{#1}}% 

    \makeindex[name=alerts,title=List of Alerts]


    \begin{document}

    Text. \AlertShort{Our strongest opening}

    More text.\AlertShort{\Cs 5-card, 4-card minor}

    Yet more text.
    \AlertShort{\Ts solid}

  And sometimes the commands occur within the text.
    \AlertShort{Here be \Ts}

    \printindex[alerts]

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easier solution than stripping the sort key after inserting it:
You can avoid adding the sort key, iff you are not in a index entry.

One way to archive this is to create a macro adding the sort key, which just gobbles its argument when you are not in a index:

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{fontspec}%
\newfontfamily\symbolfamily{Asana Math}  

\usepackage[hyperref, x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{imakeidx}\makeindex%

\usepackage[bookmarks, psdextra, unicode, hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%

\DeclareRobustCommand\Bts{{\symbolfamily\char"2663}}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \renewcommand\Bts{\Uchar"2663\relax}%
  % Inside PDF strings, \Ts is replaced by Unicode char U+2663 "BLACK CLUB SUIT"
}

\DeclareRobustCommand\Bks{{\color{red}\symbolfamily\char"2666}}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \renewcommand\Bks{\Uchar"2666\relax}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand\Bcs{{\color{red}\symbolfamily\char"2665}}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \renewcommand\Bcs{\Uchar"2665\relax}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand\Bps{{\symbolfamily\char"2660}}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \renewcommand\Bps{\Uchar"2660\relax}%
}

\newcommand\usesortkey[1]{}
\DeclareRobustCommand\myindex[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\usesortkey[1]{##1@}%
    \expanded{%
  \endgroup
      \noexpand\index[\unexpanded{#1}]{\unexpanded\expandafter{\romannumeral`\^^@#2}}%
  }
}

\newcommand{\Ts}{\usesortkey{"C}\Bts}% 
\newcommand{\Ks}{\usesortkey{"D}\Bks}% 
\newcommand{\Cs}{\usesortkey{"H}\Bcs}% 
\newcommand{\Ps}{\usesortkey{"S}\Bps}% 

\newcommand{\AlertShort}[1]{Alert: #1\myindex[alerts]{#1}}% 

\makeindex[name=alerts,title=List of Alerts]


\begin{document}

Text. \AlertShort{Our strongest opening}

More text.\AlertShort{\Cs 5-card, 4-card minor}

Yet more text.
\AlertShort{\Ts solid}

And sometimes the commands occur within the text.
\AlertShort{Here be \Ts}

\printindex[alerts]

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: Added `\expanded`, `\expandafter` and the `\romannumeral` trick to only expand the first part of the argument while the redefinition is in place, such that `\Ts` coming later are not affected. The current version requires LuaTeX for the `\expanded` primitive, this could probably be rewritten for other engines using `\edef` or a lot of `\expandafter`s.

Comment: This is certainly a much easier way of implementing the sort code and it works fine on the MWE.  For some strange reason, on my live system it's putting the symbols in among the purely textual alerts :-(  I'll investigate why.

Comment: The .idx file now contains entries such as \indexentry{4 cartes à *3@\Bcs  , \emph  {sans nier 4 cartes à *4@\Bps  }|hyperpage}{14}.  The .ilg file doesn't like that !! Input index error (file = alerts.idx, line = 34):
   -- Extra `@' at position 56 of first argument.
So the problem seems to be that the commands \Ts etc occur often as part of the text (and shouldn't have the sort code) and also occasionally at the beginning of the text where the sort code is necessary.  I'll amend the MWE accordingly.

Comment: The MWE has been amended to include an example of the sorting problem that exists on the live system.

Comment: @DLyons You can probably fix this by using romannumeral to only expand the first command with the modified usesortkey... Do you use LuaTeX? Are the \Ts always the first tokens in the argument?

Comment: Yes, I'm using LuaLateX.  The strings can have any of the \Ts commands at any position within them (and various other macros) - all that currently is working fine.  But a few strings have a  \Ts command as the head of the string - that prints OK but doesn't sort the alerts in the correct order. romannumeral is new to me - I'll look it up.

Comment: @DLyons I changed the code to restrict the effect of the redefinition

Comment: I ported it back and it's working perfectly.  Much appreciated.